# I want to develop a jigsaw puzzle with random images in android. Can any one tell how can i do this?

Tags: android

I want users to slide and arrange image parts to play jigsaw. how will i implement this. i have no idea where to start and how i will do this.please help me

Answer (score 5):

I would also suggest you to use a graphical engine like AndEngine. I suppose to be easy to implement your feature with it, but you should have at least some basics in Android development otherwise the Engine could be difficult to manage, for the lack of official documentation.

Comment: i have basic knowledge in android. I just want to know how can i do this. using any apis available or gridview or like that.

Comment: Don't be afraid and have a look at that: http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/. I don't know all the examples inside it, but you'll find something to use; your needs are commons

Answer (score 1):

Wow this is such a broad question! Maybe you should start from the very begining and advance step by step...

I suggest you do some tutorials on the official web:
[Tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial)

Maybe I am wrong and you're asking only for the graphical issue. If that's the case, this will be a good start:
[2D Graphics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html)

Comment: how do i split image and and then move the parts to form actual image ?